# WCF Service client - get Client and Server soap xml as string for internal usage

Tags: c#, wcf-client

I have a simple WCF  service client in c# that I am using:

```
   AccountsSoapClient a = new AccountsSoapClient();
    TaskResult res = a.OpenAccount();
```

Is there any way to get the client submitted sop xml and the server response?

for example:

```
AccountsSoapClient webService = new AccountsSoapClient();
bool res = webService.OpenAccount();

String client = webService.getClientSubmittedXml();
String server = webService.getServerResponseXml();
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is for logging purposes you could simply [activate tracing](http://www.atlanticbt.com/blog/listen-up-to-the-wcf-xmlwritertracelistener/). If not you could write a [custom message inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) which will allow you to capture the request/response messages. And here's a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx) illustrating a custom inspector.

Comment: Is there a way without using message inspector? Since the service contract class has many methods (services) but we want to have XML for only one of them - so do not want to snoop every service method and degrade performance or add complexities...